# How do I reload the current file?

Tags: file-operations, load

Quite often I am working with files that are version controlled, so it is possible for changes to be made to them outside of Vim.

What is a quick way to reload the file without having to close and reopen Vim? And is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: `" Compare buffer with saved version`
`nnoremap gd :DiffSaved<CR>`

Comment: If you have installed [vim-faq](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim_faq), you can get an offline answer there: `:h vim-faq` and search `/reload`. The hard to memorize tag is [`:h faq-5.8`](https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-5.8).

Answer (score 431, accepted):

The command you want is [`:e`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#edit-a-file) (short for `:edit`). If you use `:edit!` it will discard local changes and reload.

You can also have vim do this automatically with [`set autoread`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27autoread%27) in your vimrc.

Comment: See [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13092/5324) for caveats and solutions regarding `autoread`.

Comment: To do this for all buffers, use `:bufdo :e` or `:bufdo :e!`

Comment: @AaronH. thank you for that! i usually have hundreds of buffers open at a time and when switching branches, I usually just close down vim and restart to refresh all of the buffers with new contents. This will be a major timesaver!

Comment: @AaronH. The second `:` is optional: `:bufdo e` will work the same.

Comment: `nnoremap <leader>w :write \| sleep 1000m \| :checktime<CR>` 1s is the time taken by the linting tool to operate on the file. If you are using the default <leader>, type `\w` to trigger the action.

Comment: not a good idea for me because I am using `vi` for viewing files with `tab sview filename`, I can't modify anything because I can break productive code

Comment: `bd` current tab and open file again, is the only solution I have found so far

Answer (score 46):

In many cases, `set autoread` will not work as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2490635/5353461) explains:

> Autoread does not reload file unless you do something like run external command (like `!ls` or `!sh` etc)

Focus events will trigger `autoread`, but these are not captured unless using `gvim`. So, if running plain `vim` inside a terminal window or tmux, install
the plugin [vim-tmux-focus-events](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/vim-tmux-focus-events).

On tmux versions > 1.9, you'll need to add in `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g focus-events on
```

For additional goodness, adding the following to your `vimrc` will trigger `autoread` when changing buffers inside while *inside* vim:

```
au FocusGained,BufEnter * :checktime
```

Answer (score 14):

If you've ever run an external command from Vim that modifies the current buffer, you may have noticed that it prompts you to reload the file since changes have been made to disk. You can actually invoke this prompt using the `:checktime` command.

Answer (score 6):

Nice plugin to improve `autoread`
https://github.com/djoshea/vim-autoread

> Automatically causes vim to reload files which have been written on
>   disk but not modified in the buffer since the last write from vim.
>   This enables a file open in vim to be edited using another application
>   and saved. Upon returning to vim, as long as you haven't modified the
>   file since the last change, the file will be automatically updated to
>   reflect the changes made on disk, as though you had pressed :e
>   manually.

Comment: This was the best solution for me since vim-tmux-focus-events is made obsolete with vim 8.2.2345 . In this way, I also could avoid any other adjustments, such as with tmux config. Combined with rolf007's multiplayer extension, simultaneous editing of files works effortlessly. 

CoVim did not work well because it was abandoned and python2 is less available.

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem of looking at contents of a file, update the file externally, display the changed file and have the option to edit it when needed. I solved it with the Vim server/remote command line options, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10327423).

---

With the following commands a file can be reloaded via an external command. First, open the file in question with Vim, while starting a server instance.

```
vim --servername JABBERWOCKY /tmp/alice.log
```

Let's assume the file has been changed externally, e.g. by a `echo "Curiouser and curiouser" >> /tmp/alice.log`. When necessary, send a command to the server instance to reload the file. This command will finish quickly and not spawn a new editor.

```
vim --servername JABBERWOCKY --remote-send ":e<CR>"
```

If the opened file was changed in Vim and externally, there will be a conflict during reload (a warning message will appear). For that case a decision has to be made: Leave it with that and keep changes in Vim, or [discard local changes and force a reload](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/445/20471).

---

The command with `--remote-send` above requires manual reloading. However, that command could be tied to a simple loop, using Bash's `for`/`while`, or using a hacky one-liner in Linux/Unix:

```
watch -n 1 'vim --servername JABBERWOCKY --remote-send ":e<CR>"'
```

Although not tested, I'm certain that something like this could be realized in PowerShell, too.

On Linux/Unix an event-driven approach can be realized by listening to file system events using e.g. the [inotify](https://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) library, if your not using too crazy file systems. Personally I like using the tool [entr](https://github.com/clibs/entr) a lot, which seems to be included in major Linux distributions. Then I get:

```
echo /tmp/alice.log | entr vim --servername JABBERWOCKY --remote-send ":e<CR>"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, it's `:e!`, but you'll lose any changes in your buffer so be careful.

Comment: How's this different from the accepted answer?

Comment: @Friedrich there's no `!` in the short form; 

But honestly I figured it out and didn't see the accepted answer; it's kinda long.

Comment: So this one's for people who fail to figure out `:e!` is short for `:edit!` after being told `:e` was short for `:edit`. You may have a point ...

Comment: `but you'll lose any changes in your buffer`, `:h 'undoreload'`